Quota User Deletion API
Can I change quota to User Deletion API?
I found this quota:
This quota applies to User Deletion requests:
1.5 queries per second (QPS) per property or Firebase project
500 queries per day (QPD) per cloud project
But this not enough for my company project.
I cant find any information where I can change quote for User Deletion API.
